# Azure Devops Create Item API

Tags: azure, devops, azure-rest-api

I'm just following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to create a *work item* in Azure Devops.

It works. The item is being created, but it is created in the wrong backlog.

I mean my project has two backlogs and of course the new item is always being created in the wrong one and as per the documentation, I do not see how to create an item and select in which backlog should it be created.

Has anyone faced something like this?

This is the code I'm using to create an item and it works, but it creates a backlog item, but in the wrong backlog as the current project has two backlogs where tickets could be stored
`https://dev.azure.com/${companyDetails.company_name}/${azureDetails.myProject.id}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Product Backlog Item?api-version=7.0`

Comment: while sending the request for workitem creation, please provide AreaPath and IterationPath in request body like below

[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "value": "Test Work item"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
        "value": "your area path"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
        "value": "your iteration path"
    }
]

In this way, you can create the workitem in a specific backlog

Answer (score 0):

You can create an item in a specific backlog by using `"path": "/fields/System.AreaPath"` and `"path": "/fields/System.IterationPath"` parameter in your request body. You can refer to this [doc](https://medium.com/@sandeepsinh/create-work-item-with-rest-api-in-azure-devops-28f979a12f37) as well.

[image]

You can get the AreaPath and IterationPath from below

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]